# Breaking a while loop from other method inside the same class in Python

Tags: python

I am wondering if I can run a `while` loop inside a method of a Python class that can be stopped from another method.

For example, something like this:

```
from time import sleep

class example():

    global recording

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        global recording
        recording = True
        while recording:
            print(1)

    def stop(self):
        global recording
        recording = False
        print("SLEEEPINGGGGGGGGGGG")

a = example()
a.start()
sleep(0.5)
a.stop()
```

But, it does not work, the loop does not stop.

**EDIT**
Since I do not want to create a Thread outside the class, I just tried this, but it doesn't work either.

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_running = False

    def start(self):
        self.is_running = True
        self.loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main_loop)

    def main_loop(self):
        while self.is_running:
            sleep(0.5)
            print(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print("SLEEEPINGGGGGGGGGGG")

a = example()
a.start()
sleep(3)
a.stop()
```

Comment: you would need some threading for that. and use a member data instead of a global!

Comment: Could you please illustrate it with a simple example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a.start()` is an infinite loop. Since nothing runs at the same time, it just runs and never reaches the next statements.

You need to create a thread, like this

```
import time,threading

class example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.__recording = False

    def start(self):
        self.__recording = True
        while self.__recording:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.__recording = False

a = example()
t = threading.Thread(target=a.start)
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
a.stop()
t.join()
```

note that I have used a member variable instead of a global. When the `start` method sees that the variable is `True`, it quits the loop. job done.

That works because I'm using `sleep()`. If you're running a pure python CPU intensive job that won't work because of python GIL

As suggested in comments, you can go one step further and inherit from `threading.Thread` method instead:

```
import time,threading

class example(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,target=self.run)

        self.__recording = False

    def run(self):
        self.__recording = True
        while self.__recording:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(1)

    def join(self):
        self.__recording = False
        threading.Thread.join(self)

a = example()
a.start()
time.sleep(5)
a.join()
```

Note that `stop` method is now replaced by `join` which signals the recording thread to stop then calls the parent `join` method. So when you `join` you stop the loop automatically first.

Comment: It's also common to subclass `Thread` and override the `run()` method to achieve this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach that's even better, yes.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Could you please provide me a simple example?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you! But I'm facing another problem. I just want to encapsulate all in the class, in order to just need to call start() and stop() without creating Threads outside it. I tried to do it using your code, but I could not figure it. I have updated the comment, can you revise it?

Comment: I've updated my answer following Sven comments, I think that's the same thing you're asking for (you can rename `join`  to `stop` BTW)

Comment: @VíctorMartínez I just gave it a shot as well – see https://ideone.com/sgQS6i.  It's more or less identical to Jean-François' solution here, except that I chose to add a `stop()` method instead of changing the behaviour of `join()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes, maybe I outdid it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your thread after initiating it:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

class example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_running = False

    def start(self):
        self.is_running = True
        self.loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.main_loop)
        self.loop_thread.start() # <--- you forgot to start your thread

    def main_loop(self):
        while self.is_running:
            sleep(0.5)
            print(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print("SLEEEPINGGGGGGGGGGG")

a = example()
a.start()
sleep(3)
a.stop()
```